# ExtJS: How to load additional script on a specific `Window` component?

Tags: javascript, extjs, window, share, mixins

I'm try to create a `Window` which will show [AddToAny share buttons](https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/for/website). I need to set *AddToAny*'s required `script` under this window. I've google similar question within Social Media buttons.

- I learned that `Mashup` class could work. I've create a `mixin` class but unfortunately this is not working.
- As well saved related JS library under project files and tried to call it through `html` config but this isn't work either.

How can I achieve to my aim?

```
//Here is related function. 
onMoreShare: function () {
        new Ext.window.Window({
            // requires: ['MyApp.mixins.ShareApps'], //Tried to load JS file to Window
            title: 'More...',
            autoShow: true,
            modal: true,
            padding: 20,
            html: '<a class="a2a_dd" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"><img src="https://static.addtoany.com/buttons/share_save_171_16.png" width="171" height="16" border="0" alt="Share"></a>\n' +
            // Mixin didn't work; tried original code...
            // '<script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>\n' +
            // Mixin didn't work; tried to call js file through project
            //'<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../resources/js/addToAny.js"></script>\n'
        });
    }

//Created this `Mashup` based class to load related JS file.
Ext.define('MyApp.mixins.ShareApps', {
    mixins: ['Ext.mixin.Mashup'],

    requiredScripts: [
        '//static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js'
    ]
});
```

Comment: Can't you just put <script async src=https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js></script> in the head of index.html ?

Comment: @FabioBarros I've tried already but did not work!?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this fiddle:

[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2l76&view/editor)

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.widget('window', {
            width: 300,
            height: 250,
            padding: 5,
            title: 'Hello World',
            html: '<div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style"> '+
                  '<a class="a2a_dd" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"></a> '+
                  '<a class="a2a_button_facebook"></a> '+
                  '<a class="a2a_button_twitter"></a> '+
                  '<a class="a2a_button_google_plus"></a> '+
                  '</div>'
        }).show();
    }
});
```

Index page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: As I told up there even I've stated script on index.html it did not work. My app created with Sencha CMD; Therefore I've tried to request to this script through `app.json`'s `js` section as well and I've tried to use `Mashup` mixin but none of them are let me use AddToAny's scripts :|

Comment: this is Sencha doc for microloader @ https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.6.0/guides/microloader.html#microloader_-_js